# stopping download when internet is not working?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to fix this for days now, but to no avail. Essentially, what I'm doing is this:

- starting a Service for every file name in an Array
- services are put in a queue and they are processed one at a time
        - each service downloads a file from a server  < == problem is here

When I'm downloading a file sometimes the internet on the mobile phone, especially the WIFI one it doesnt respond in that pages don't load and the download stops or gets stuck at lets say 25%. Now I want to find out when this happens so that I can stop the Service and have been trying to do this for days now but nothing works. This is what I have so far:

```
 URL url = new URL(full_url);
 HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 //conexion.setConnectTimeout(10000);
 conexion.connect();


    while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0 && lenghtOfFile > 0){
               total += count;
               downloadProgress = (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile);
               Log.e("downloadProgress","" + downloadProgress);
               output.write(data, 0, count);

    }
```

This is what I usually get when the files are being downloaded:
File 1:
download Progress: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ... 100

and then File 2 something similar:
download Progress: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ... 100

and let's say on File 3 the internet will go down (not disconnected just pages won't load)
and I get something like this:
File 3:
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3  4 4 4 4 4 4  5  5 5 5 5 5 5  6 6 6 6 6 6  7 7 7 7 7 7 
 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 (internet goes down, gets stuck at 9)

How do I add a method that checks when this happens so that I can stop the Service!

I really need urgent help on this, thanks for your time!

**EDIT**:
This the LOG that I get when Internet gets stuck while downloading a file. The download as you can see has gone to 29% and then the internet connection becomes unresponsive in some way in which it doesn't throw any Exception it just stay like that!

```
11-16 16:18:39.769: ERROR/totaltotal(24691): 29
11-16 16:18:39.859: ERROR/totaltotal(24691): 29
11-16 16:18:39.869: ERROR/totaltotal(24691): 29
11-16 16:18:39.869: ERROR/totaltotal(24691): 29
11-16 16:18:39.879: ERROR/totaltotal(24691): 29
11-16 16:19:04.119: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(162): reportNetworkCondition(1, 0)
11-16 16:19:04.119: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(162): Inet connectivity change, net=1, condition=0,mActiveDefaultNetwork=1
11-16 16:19:04.119: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(162): starting a change hold
11-16 16:19:05.940: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:05.940: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:05.950: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:07.129: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(162): Inet hold end, net=1, condition =0, published condition =0
11-16 16:19:07.129: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(162): no change in condition - aborting
11-16 16:19:15.959: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:15.959: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:15.969: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:25.979: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:25.979: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
11-16 16:19:25.989: DEBUG/BatteryService(162): update start
```

Comment: First of all, are you sure you want to do this with Service, not AsyncTask or threadpool? Do you use IntentService or handle thread in your service yourself? start service 100 times download 100 files doesn't look reasonable for me.

Comment: I'm using my own implementation of Service. I have a Thread that control a queue which holds the downloads. It works fine, that's not the problem, the prob is how to stop the service when the internet is no accessible (while still being connected to the network)

Answer (score 1):

Line input.read(data) will give an IOException when the connection is lost.
Make sure you catch the exception while doing those reads.

Comment: Yes, I'm catching the Exception. As I mentioned this is not the case where the connection is lost. This is the case when the device is connected to the internet but web pages and http request do not work.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is call `setReadTimeout()` on your `connexion` object before you call `connect()`.   This will cause the underlying socket `read(...)` calls to throw an exception if they take too long.  Choose a timeout that corresponds to your notion of the internet  not being working.

Hypothetically, if you had a reliable way of detecting that "the internet is not working", you could have another thread reach in and close the stream.  I think this will unblock the thread that is blocked in the `read(...)` call on the stream that was just closed.

---

Bear in mind that it is impossible to distinguish *a priori* between a short outage (e.g. one which will resolve itself when you get out of the lift) and a long one.

Comment: I was thinking of having some Thread or just a routine that checks the value of the downloadProgress variable. If that value stays the same for let's say 20 sec then I know that the internet is stuck and I end the service but I have no idea how to do that!!!

Comment: @user967232 - my answer gives you a way to do that (2nd paragraph).

Comment: yes by closing the stream it would cause an Exception next time read tries to run, right? and so that way i will be able to do something. But how do i get the part  where I detect if the internet is not working.

Comment: I'm trying to think of way to somehow monitor the variable downloadProgress. If that variable stays the same at one value for at least 20 secs or more than I will close the stream and end the service, but how do I monitor the variable downloadProgress.

Comment: No.  I'm thinking that closing the connection in another thread would cause the *current* read to fail with an exception.  But the setReadTimeout() approach is probably easier to implement.  Why don't you try that?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work this what it gives me when the internet gets stuck. I edited my question and included the LOG.